# DOM Listener on Static Table Change

Tags: javascript, dom, events, listener, dom-events

I'm trying to add listener to my table in order to call another jJavascript function.

My app is a simple upload script, when user chooses a file it uploads and creates new row in the table. Therefore at each creation of new row I would like to call a Javascript function.

My sample code is the following:

```
$("#fayls").bind("DOMNodeInserted", function() {
    $(".chzn-select").chosen();
    alert('ha cambiato')
});
```

Where `fayls` is the id of my table.

When I run this code, it calls this event infinitely instead of just one.

How should I solve this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the row inserted contain those elements converted by chosen?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question :/

Comment: what does chosen() do? What happens if you comment it out

Comment: For each uploaded element I want users to choose tags from the dropdown menu. And for that menu I use chosen, http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ for better UI. Therefore I need to call chosen() function in order to improve the view for dropdown menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you all mentioned, the problem is caused from chosen, for each drop box item in chosen, it fires the DOM event, therefore I'll have infinite loop.

I found a simple solution by just filtering the unnecessary events:

```
 $("#listenMe").bind("DOMNodeInserted", function(event) {

        var targetName =  event.target.nodeName.toString() ;
        if (targetName == "TR") {
            $(".chzn-select").chosen();
            //alert('ha cambiato - Event Node Name:' + event.target.nodeName)
        }
    });
```

Therefore it only runs when a new row added into a table

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in that Chosen plugin converts, among all others, elements inside that container with `"#fayls"` ID. Consider this:

HTML:

```
<div id="something"></div>
<div id="completely_different"></div>
<button id="change_something" type="button">Change!</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#change_something').click(function() {
    $('#something').append($('<p>Internal P</p>'));
});
$('#something').bind("DOMNodeInserted", function(event) {
    alert(event.target);
    $("#completely_different").append($('<p>SOme p</p>'));
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bPEQn/2/)

It works as expected (each click on the button adds a `<p>` element into boths divs).

Now let's change our HTML slightly:

```
<div id="something">
    <div id="completely_different"></div>
</div>
<button id="change_something" type="button">Change!</button>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bPEQn/)

... and now the event will be fired indefinitely - because when we update the inner div, the DOMNodeInserted still bubbles up to the outer one.

Also note that DOMNodeInserted event is, well, considered [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events) now (but still its support is buggy in IE9, as described [here](http://help.dottoro.com/ljmcxjla.php)).

Comment: yes, you're absolutely right. When I deactivate chosen, everything works perfectly. However is there anyway to make this with chosen ? Can I add any listener to my table that lets me know when new TR added or sth else ?

Comment: How about attaching the listener on <tbody> instead? Anyway, I'd suggest getting rid of MutatorEvent handler completely, triggering instead a custom event in your AJAX response processor. You can safely listen for that event instead.

Comment: I see.. Is there any good article or tutorial about custom event creation ?

Comment: Check [this one](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-custom-events/). But in fact, using `.bind` and `.trigger` is pretty straight-forward.

Answer (score 1):

You has the problem because the event will be dispatched also at the parent nodes  (bubbles)

From W3C

> DOMNodeInserted:
>    - Fired when a node has been added as a child of another node. 
>    - This event is dispatched after the insertion has taken place.
>    - The target of this event is the node being inserted. 
>    - Bubbles: Yes 
>    - Cancelable: No
>    - Context Info: relatedNode holds the parent node

try to dispatch a custom event when add the row and bind it for update the combobox

to bind event use:

```
$('#something').bind('row.added', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    //your code here
}
```

to trigger the event (after row is added) use:

```
$('#something').trigger('row.added');
```

Comment: yes that's what I'm looking for, is there any tutorial or article about dispatch a custom event ?

Comment: I updated my code with respect to your example, but now event is not fired, nothing happens

Comment: @CanCeylan can you post a snippet of your code or create a jsfiddle?